# Android doesn't respect the android:fillColor in SVG path - How can we workaround on this limitation?

Tags: android, svg

By using the following XML

### layout.xml with red tint color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_check_circle_24"
        app:tint="#ff0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and specific the path fill color in SVG.

### baseline_check_circle_24.svg with white path fill color

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z"/>
</vector>
```

I am expecting a **red circle with white tick symbol**

However, this is what I am getting

### Outcome

[image]

It seems that Android doesn't respect the `android:fillColor` in SVG path.

May I know, how can I make the tick symbol solid white color?